# Decision tree classifier fit function throwing error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'E-50'"

Tags: python, jupyter, decision-tree

I am trying to fit data taken from xlsx file with decision tree classifier but i am getting error "ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'E-50'".

Following is my code from my Jupyter Notebook:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import tree
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
results = pd.read_excel("new3.xlsx")
Y = np.array(results.values[:, 1:9])
X=  np.array(results.values[:,0])
X_Train,X_Test,Y_Train,Y_Test= train_test_split(X,Y, test_size = 0.3, 
random_state = 176)
model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_Train,Y_Train)
```

Comment: Where does the error occur?  My guess it's the `read_excel` line, where text is being loaded and converted (if possible) to a dataframe.  Evidently the text includes this 'E-50' string, which is not a valid float value.

Comment: This error occurs at line model.fit(X_Train,Y_Train).

Comment: Well, then make sure you understand the nature of the `X_Train` and `Y_Train` arrays.   What's the shape?  What's the dtype?  The `read_excel` must have read one or more columns as strings.

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me solve my problem.